# How to download a remote file in PHP fast?

Tags: php, url, download, protocols, wrapper

I found this script in php.net which allows the users to download a local file. Whenever I try to use a protocol at the front of the file name, PHP can't find the file. I have enabled allow_url_fopen in php.net. What should I do to allow remote files to be downloaded?

Furthermore, the download is really slow even with the help of download managers. Are there any things I can do to increase the download speed? Is there a way to allow the 'resume download' option in the download managers?

```
<?php
$file = 'https://www.example.com/test.exe';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else echo "file not found."
?>
```

Comment: If a file downloads slowly, try increasing the bandwidth available to the server or downloading user. Running this script will always make it slower than the user just downloading the file directly

Comment: you dont add a protocol to the attachment header there is no need to

Comment: @Anigel: Sorry I must disagree. A middle-man download can be faster.

Comment: @DaveChen not something I have ever experienced without weird firewall rules or very strange proxy configurations. Even if server B has more bandwidth than server A, the file can only get to a user via server B as fast as server A could have sent it to the user.

Comment: The `file_exists()` call will be expensive and slow down the start of the transfer (you are making 2 requests to the remote server), but if the transfer itself is slow then the problem is simply bandwidth. You need a more granular control over the request, which [cURL](http://php.net/curl) can give you, you'll want to use the `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` callback to control whether the response from the remote server is forwarded on to the client. Alternatively you may want to look at a proper HTTP client library, but this would require a more extensive knowledge of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Can someone tell me why I can't download a remote file in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

"Resume download" requires implementing the `Range` header. You would have to take this header from your request headers and pass it on to the back end when you send a request. Apparently it's possible to set the headers that will be sent when using the HTTP-protocol wrapper of `fopen` (let's see if I find an example of this...)

If the file  to download is publicly accessible over the internet why don't you redirect the user there with a `Location` header? That would remove your server from the data path, probably giving the fastest option possible.

Your second best option is configuring the a reverse proxy on the web server, [for example with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html). This at least takes the PHP interpreter out of the equation.

Comment: I need to hide the real download URL from the users. The problem with the 'Location' header is that it shows the download URL in the download managers.

Comment: Then I would recommend using either a dedicated reverse proxy or configuring the web server as one